# Div is created upon submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, reactjs

I'm new to web development, and I'm currently in the process of building a trip planner. I have an activity div where when you click the plus sign a form slide down to insert the information about this activity. essentially I want to create a div with the entered information in this form every time a user hit submit. I have no idea what is this called, or how it could be implemented, any feedback is highly appreciated.

[image: see the image]

Comment: I would look into having the div hidden by default, and then becoming visible after a click. Something along the lines of **<div id="myId" style="display: none;">**, and a script that will change the display style **onClick()**

Comment: I'm not the down voter but your question is too general to answer. You might want to rephrase and be more specific so people can actually help you. Have you tried working on this solution? If not, try it then come back here where you are stucked.

Comment: To expand on that, I'm not sure if it's actually possible to create a div like that. It would be much simpler to already have the div loaded with the rest of the page and just reveal it when you need your user to see it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @JohnnyQ believe me if I knew what it is called, I wouldn't post this question, but I'll consider what you said next time :)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to make a function to dynamically create the elements you want to show to the user and call that function on the submit button's onClick handler.

That could look like this:

```
function create() {
    var parent = document.createElement('div');
    parent.className = 'parent';

    //you would have a child element for each bit of data the user has input
    var child = document.createElement('div');
    child.className = 'child';
    parent.appendChild(child);

    //append the newly created div to your container
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(parent);
}
```

Then add this to the buttons onclick listener

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', create);
```

This will have the advantage of being able to be called multiple times if the same user is inputting data more than once.

However if this only needs to be shown once you could just have everything already there but not displayed and set it's display property to 'inline-block' instead of 'none'

If you want you can then use the CSS animation property to slide the div down (or whatever animations you want).

Answer (score 0):

Write the html code for the form div. Save it as text in a variable

```
(var html = "...")
```

and use jQuery

```
$("#divId").append(html)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it

Answer (score 0):

```js
function  createDiv(){
var i=1;
            var ele = document.createElement("div");
            ele.setAttribute("id","DivId"+i);
            ele.setAttribute("class","inner");
            ele.innerHTML="hi "+i;
            output.appendChild(ele);
  
  }
```

```html
<div id="output" class="out">

</div>
<input type="button" onclick="createDiv();" name="submit" >
```

Comment: Thank you , this is what I was trying to accomplish!